# EXCEL highlight all the rows with same value in specific cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I work on table like this:

| id | seller | state | reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bla1 | approved | not supported |
| 1 | bla2 | rejected | rejected by seller |
| 2 | bla3 | rejected | rejected by seller |
| 2 | bla3 | failed | error |
| 3 | bla1 | failed | failed to get |
| 3 | bla2 | pending | failed to get |
| 4 | bla4 | rejected | not supported |

I want to highlight the rows based on the id column - rows with id = 1 will be highlighted with one color, rows with id = 2 will be highlighted with second color, etc. 
I didn't find an option to this with conditional formatting. 
Will appreciate any help.

Comment: How many different IDs? if too many, that could be a lot of eye-boggling colours and lots of rules to manage (and note that conditional formats are always volatile). Have you considered allowing the user to choose just one or two ids through a drop-down list in a cell for example, and colouring only those?

Comment: See also [Change Fill Color for Entire Row  when Value in a Cell Changes](https://superuser.com/q/1509379/150988).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following .gif

I take rows with id = 2 as an example, they will be highlighted with red.
Used the formula:

```
=$A1=2
```

Other ids are similar.
[image]

Comment: how do you make GIFs like this ? +1 btw

Comment: @PeterH I use ScreenToGif.

Comment: How I do it automatically for each id?